# Google map does not display correctly in jupyter notebook

Tags: pandas, google-maps-api-3, jupyter-notebook, geojson

I'm trying to use google map API to visualize some data in jupyter notebook. Here is the code I used to display basic map in jupyter:

```
import gmaps
import os
import json
import gmaps.datasets

gmaps.configure(api_key="AIz....")

fig=gmaps.figure()

fig
```

After I ran the code, nothing was displayed. I used my own google API key and couldn't figure out why the map isn't displayed. I'm new to the geojson field, so any idea or thoughts is appreciated.

Comment: Have you followed all steps described in https://github.com/pbugnion/gmaps ?

Answer (score 9):

Did you make sure Widgets are enabled in your jupyter? try this before you run Jupyter:

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py gmaps
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JupyterLab you can check out the steps in the documentation here
[JupyterLab Documentation](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/extensions.html)